# Convert an array of objects to sorted array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I have an arrays of objects, lets say

```
[{a:'one',aa:'eleven'},{a:'two',aa:'twelve'},{a:'three',aa:'thirteen'}]
```

I want to convert the objects into arrays, something like this

```
[['one','eleven'], ['two','twelve'],['three','thirteen']]
```

as property name should map to a given correct index in the array

Is this possible using Lodash or javascript?

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: It looks like order would matter so you would need some kind of map (property "a" goes into array slot 1, property "aa" goes into array slot 2, and so on)

Comment: That was what I was thinking. A simple `sort` may not be correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a an approach using [lodash#map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) with a [lodash#unary](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unary) wrapped `lodash#map` iteratee.

```
var result = _.map(data, _.unary(_.map));
```

```js
var data = [{a:'one',aa:'eleven'},{a:'two',aa:'twelve'},{a:'three',aa:'thirteen'}];

var result = _.map(data, _.unary(_.map));

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

**Update**
To preserve key orders, you may replace the `lodash#map` iteratee into [lodash#at](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at) that is [partially](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight) applied with the `keys` that defines the order of the values.

```
var keys = ['aa', 'a'];
var result = _.map(data, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.at, keys)));
```

```js
var data = [{a:'one',aa:'eleven'},{a:'two',aa:'twelve'},{a:'three',aa:'thirteen'}];

var keys = ['aa', 'a'];
var result = _.map(data, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.at, keys)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

An es6 alternative of the solution above would be:

```
var keys = ['aa', 'a'];
var result = _.map(data, v => _.at(v, keys));
```

```js
var data = [{a:'one',aa:'eleven'},{a:'two',aa:'twelve'},{a:'three',aa:'thirteen'}];

var keys = ['aa', 'a'];
var result = _.map(data, v => _.at(v, keys));

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can we make sure we place certain key at a particular index

Answer (score 5):

If certain keys in the original objects must go to specific slots in the array, then you can create a map of key to slot number.

```js
var data = [{
  a: 'one',
  aa: 'eleven'
}, {
  a: 'two',
  aa: 'twelve'
}, {
  a: 'three',
  aa: 'thirteen'
}];

var keyToSlot = {
  a: 0,
  aa: 1
};

var result = data.map(function(entry) {
  var keys = Object.keys(entry);
  return keys.reduce(function(acc, key) {
    var slot = keyToSlot[key];
    acc[slot] = entry[key];
    return acc;
  }, []);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by grabbing the keys of every object, sorting them, and then mapping them to an array.

```js
const arr = [{a:'one',aa:'eleven'},{a:'two',aa:'twelve'},{a:'three',aa:'thirteen'}]
const res = arr.map(x => Object.keys(x).sort().map(y => x[y]));

console.log(res)
```

Step by step:

- `arr.map` iterates through each object

  - `Object.keys(x).sort()` gets the keys of the object and sorts them alphabetically.
  - `.map(y => x[y])` on the above result turns the keys of the objects into the respective values.

Comment: but i also need the keys to be at particular index in the array, the keys will not be guranteed in same order

Comment: @ua_boaz the `sort()` call on the keys guarantees order does it not? You need to specify some way to sort the keys, and in this case I chose alphabetical.

Comment: @ua_boaz it's impossible to say to sort the object in the order that you wrote the keys in your code if that's what you want.